# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'gradient' scipy python

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am optimizing a linear function with scipy,

```
   def func(weights):
        var = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
        if weights is None:
           weights = np.ones(len(var)) / len(var)
        return len(set([var[i] for i in range(len(weights)) if weights[i]>0]))/len(var)

res = minimize(lambda x: func(x), x0=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25],method='SLSQP',
                       jac=ad.gh(lambda x: func(x))[0], bounds=((0.,1.),)*4,
                       options = {'disp':True, 'ftol': 1e-20, 'maxiter': 1000},
                       constraints= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - 1.0})
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/applicatio/Sub Applicatio/main.py", line 338, in <module>
    constraints= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - 1.0})
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 455, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 383, in _minimize_slsqp
    g = append(fprime(x),0.0)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 289, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\python-3.5.1.amd64\lib\site-packages\ad\__init__.py", line 1090, in grad
    return numpy.array(ans.gradient(list(xa)))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'gradient'
```

How can I optimize this kind of simple linear function ? Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're using SLSQP; doesn't that *require* you to pass in the Jacobian in the constraints?

Comment: The error looks like your derivative definition is 1D whereas your function is 4D. What size is  `ad.gh(lambda x:func(x))[0]` ?

Comment: Because of the coupling of `if`,`set` and `len`, are you sure the derivatives do exist in the defined space?

Comment: @Prune No gradient is all required. I have used exact similar syntax with another method and it was working fine

Answer (score 2):

What on earth is your `func` doing?

```
def func(weights):
    ....
    return len(set())/len(var)
```

You get a `set` object, and then it's length, the number of terms.  What does that represent?   That's not linear; it takes integer jumps.

```
In [318]: x0=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]
In [319]: def func(weights):
     ...:         var = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
     ...:         if weights is None:
     ...:            weights = np.ones(len(var)) / len(var)
     ...:         return len(set([var[i] for i in range(len(weights)) if weights
     ...: [i]>0]))/len(var)
     ...:     
In [320]: func(x0)
Out[320]: 1.0
In [321]: x0=np.array(x0)
In [322]: func(x0)
Out[322]: 1.0
In [323]: func(x0+.1)
Out[323]: 1.0
In [324]: func(x0-.1)
Out[324]: 1.0
In [325]: func(x0-1)
Out[325]: 0.0
```

In fact all it does is count how many of the `x0` values are `>0` and divide by 4 - so it generates 0,.25,.5,.75 or 1.

`minimize` is going start with `x0`, and figure out how `func(x0)` varies with small changes in `x0`.

And your `jac`, is something based of this `func` as well, `jac=ad.gh(lambda x: func(x))[0]`

==============

I don't think you need to use the `lambda`

```
 `lambda x: func(x)`
```

Just give `func` as the argument.  It takes the correct number of arguments (e.g. the initial `x0`).

===================

Running your code, but without the `jac` parameter (I don't know what `ad.gh` is):

```
In [543]: def func(weights):
     ...:         var = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
     ...:         if weights is None:
     ...:            weights = np.ones(len(var)) / len(var)
     ...:         return len(set([var[i] for i in range(len(weights)) if weights
     ...: [i]>0]))/len(var)
     ...:     
In [544]: optimize.minimize(lambda x: func(x), x0=[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25],method='
     ...: SLSQP',bounds=((0.,1.),)*4,options = {'disp':True, 'ftol': 1e-20, 'max
     ...: iter': 1000},constraints= {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) - 1.0
     ...: })
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 1.0
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 6
            Gradient evaluations: 1
Out[544]: 
     fun: 1.0
     jac: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 6
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 0.25,  0.25,  0.25,  0.25])
```

It looks like it's trying small changes around `x0`, and finds that there isn't any variation (small changes don't make any elements go to 0).  To put it another way, your `func` is already at a local minimum, a flat region.

Comment: @hpaulij Actually you are right.. I am actually counting the number of x0 values if >0. Actually I am running a multiobjective optimization and I have 2 other objectives which are working perfectly fine. I was just not understanding how to minimize this function. I have tried your way without lambda function but then it throws "TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: Do you expect the solution to be 3 0 terms and a 1, max number of 0s but summing to 1?  Can you remove the `jac` parameter?

Comment: It runs without the `jac` parameter.